# What slide ratio is more appropriate if I don't know the screen size?

Tags: presentation-design

I've got to make a presentation but I don't know the ratio of the screen it will be viewed on. It will also have to be available in printable version (A4). What slide ratio is more appropriate given these constraints? Any suggestions?

Comment: You must have some constraints on the software you can use? Or are you plugging your own device into the screen? Will other people need to re-use your content? What size paper will your print need to be?

Comment: They will view and print it, with programs and devices unknown to me. I may use any software. Paper size A4, I have edited the question to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use A4 landscape to match your printed output.

Any software likely to be used for on-screen display (Acrobat, Powerpoint, Impress, a video player) should be able to scale this proportionally to fit the display device in full-screen mode, leaving black bars at top and bottom.

A4, at 1.414 ratio, is a bit wider than traditional 1.33 screens, so will be a reasonable compromise for widescreens (usually 1.6 or 1.78)

Comment: So you're basically saying I should choose the ratio that best adapts to the other ratios. Good point. 1.4 also adapts well to 1.33.

Answer (score 1):

1024x768 is to my knowledge the most common "safe" resolution. Most beamers support it.

If you use powerpoint then your layout can get compromised if the resolution is very different or if the font is missing. So maybe also look into font-embedding or consider Acrobat as a format.

Comment: I will use formats SVG and PDF.

Comment: I don't think SVG is a good format for presentation. What programm will you use to show it?

Comment: I'm subject to the constraint SVG + PDF, I don't know what program will be used to show it. I don't know if one can view directly the SVG, I may guess that SVG is required as the 'source', but the truth is that I don't know for sure.

Comment: Then I would go the way of Illustrator. Set up Artboards in 1024x768 and export the final design to PDF as well as SVG. SVG might need every artboard to be exported seperately, but there are scripts for that.

Comment: I use Inkscape, however thank you for information.

Comment: Re "Powerpoint.. your layout can get compromised if the resolution is very different" - you'll get stretching if the screen doesn't match your output resolution and can't scale proportionally, but this is an OS/hardware issue, not Powerpoint, which will always scale proportionally.

Comment: I was not talking about stretching but how the text wrap can change when screen sizes differ or a font is missing. A problem I have often seen in powerpoint presentations.